# How do I tag someone in a status in Facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-tags

How do I tag friends in a status update on Facebook?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply preface a person's name with an `@` sign when you type it in a status.  For instance, if you want to tag your friend `Joe Someone` in your status, begin by typing `@Joe`.  Facebook will automatically open a drop down where you can select his name.

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes the specific target you want to reference is not among the handful of suggestions in the dropdown menu that pops up next to your `@`:

## To reference any target on Facebook even when it is not listed in the suggestions dropdown after typing the `@`:

For users and groups which have a username defined and for pages, you can use the target’s **name from the URL** in the address bar to put behind the @:
**Example**: [https://www.facebook.com/**80000Hours**/](https://www.facebook.com/80000Hours/) → **`@80000Hours`**
For **groups**, keeping the prefix `groups/` can help:
**Example**: [https://www.facebook.com/**groups/effective.altruists**/](https://www.facebook.com/groups/effective.altruists/) → **`@group/effective.altrui`**
Note that I left out the `s` in `groups/` and the ending …`sts` of `effective.altruists`.  That’s because Facebook only matches up to 22 characters after the `@`.  From the 23rd character on, the dropdown disappears.  `groups/` works as well as `group/`, but leaves one character less to specify the target’s name.

Users that you’re not connected to  can not be tagged by default, but they can enable it.
**Example**: [`@strohl89`](https://www.facebook.com/strohl89)

Unfortunately, I don’t know yet what to do about users who don’t have a
username (username example: [https://www.facebook.com/**wdmacaskill**](https://www.facebook.com/wdmacaskill))
(so they only have the numerical ID ([https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=**100011278218122**](https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100011278218122))).
I’d greatly appreciate a comment if someone knows!

Comment: Can you delete whichever one of these answers that you don't want to keep, please?

Comment: @jonsca, ✔ Oops, thanks for the heads-up!  (Evidently I opened this question twice in parallel, thinking these were 2 different questions.)  It’s done – feel free to delete both our comments.

Comment: @jonsca, also thanks for the explanation in your [rejection](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/85227) of my edit suggestion! :)  I dropped a comment there instead, as you suggested.  This comment here, is like the previous one meant for burning-after-reading. :)

Comment: You shouldn't be pasting duplicate answers to different questions in any case. If you're doing that then the questions are very likely duplicates and one of them should be closed as such.

Comment: @ale, thanks, the {duplicates should be closed part} is a valid point and would obviously have been the case in my misinterpreted scenario, haha!  (I wasn’t motivated to compare the ‘2’ questions, but I should have.  Then I would have noticed, they are suspiciously similar … ;) )  Anyway, do you have a source for the rule that one shouldn’t paste duplicate answers?  To me it seems to be reasonable to even duplicate a good answer before closing the respective question(s). …

Comment: @ale, … You may also want to compare this question here with http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/3220/facebook-tagging-things-youre-not-related-to?rq=1 for duplication.  I pasted my answer to both – it seemed fitting, even though they seem different enough to me not to be duplicates.  But with your experience you are probably better equipped to make such a judgment call.

Comment: (@ale, besides, how could that rule possibly be universal, since then there could only be at most one question with the appropriate answer [“You should totally drop that and try jQuery!”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19492#19492) ;) )

Comment: For one thing, duplicate answers automatically get flagged for the Moderators to look at. Also, from the Stack Exchange FAQ: [Is it acceptable to add a duplicate answer to several questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/104227/21960)

Comment: Also: [Why were all my copy/pasted answers to duplicate questions deleted?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/178223/21960) and [Answering the same question across the site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/177079/21960)

Comment: @ale, thank you for the informative links!